# Rails Search option inside an application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. And i have already done a small application, which is used to create a contact and it's details. And now, In that application i want to add the following feature

1. Add a search box
2. As you type in the search box, relevant contacts that matches the search result should be displayed right below that search box as a suggest.
3. Clicking on a contact in the search result should redirect to that contact page.

I could not get any ideas , so please some one help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this Autocomplete search box?

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

And modify that autocomplete function as your requirement.

javascript will work like this

```
var source = '' ;
$( "input#autocomplete" ).keyup(function() {
     $.get( "/contacts-json?q="+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
          source =  data ;
        });
});

var NoResultsLabel = "No Results";
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({    
    source : function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(source, request.term);

        if (!results.length) {
            results = [NoResultsLabel];
        }

        response(results);
    },
    select : function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (ui.item.label === NoResultsLabel) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $("input#autocomplete").val(ui.item.label);
            window.location.href = ui.item.value; //give redirect url to contact details page
        }
    },
    messages : {
        results : function(event, ui) {

        }
    }
});
```

I have one text box in view file,

```
<input id="autocomplete" class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

In controller,

```
def contacts_json
 @program = Contact.all
 @formatted_contacts = []
 @searched_contacts = []
 Contact.where("title LIKE ?", "#{params[:q]}%" ).each do |contact|
  @searched_contacts << {value: contact.to_param, label: contact.title}  
 end
  @formatted_contacts = @searched_contacts.uniq {|e| e[:value]} //to get unique contact
  @formatted_contacts = @formatted_contacts.to_json    
  render json: @formatted_contacts
end
```

In route file,

```
  get 'contacts-json' => 'contacts#contacts_json', as: :all_contacts_json
```

Comment: i need to interact with database. In this case how can i do.

Comment: @karthik i have updated my answer. Follow this step and also attach javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) gem, this should be easy to implement.